# How to add more attributes with json data

Tags: python, json, django

I have implemented code like this.

```
message_body = "message body"
message_title = "message title"
badge = 1
data_message = {
        "type":"1100",
        "class_id":"10",
    }

if(condition):
        # add more attributes with already existing attributes
        data_message = {
            "message_body" : message_body,
            "message_title" : message_title,
            "badge" : badge,
        }
        return data_message
else:
        # without any changes in data_message
        return data_message
```

If pass the if condition I got only message_body, message_title, badge. I could not receive type and class_id. i want to get all of these if pass the IF conditon. could anyone suggest anyway to do this?

Comment: this is dictionary so you should use update method to update dictionary and will not replace it and let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 2):

use [dict update](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm)

```
if(condition):
    # add more attributes with already existing attributes
    data_message.update({'extra_key': 'extra_value'})
return data_message
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use update method

```
data_message.update({
            "message_body" : message_body,
            "message_title" : message_title,
            "badge" : badge,
        })
```

Comment: With fixed keys which all are valid Python identifiers, I prefer this syntax:  `data_message = dict(type=1100, class_id=10)` and updating works likewise: `data_message.update(message_body=message_body, message_title=message_title, badge=badge)`